# Does an absolutely continuous distribution function imply continuity of conditional expectation?

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation, absolute-continuity

Let $(\theta_1,\theta_2) \in [0,1]^2$ be a two-dimensional random variable with a absolutely continuous joint distribution $F$ with full support. Can we say $\mathbb{E}(\theta_2|\theta_1)$ is continuous in $\theta_1$? A proof or a counterexample would be equally welcome.

My approach: $\mathbb{E}(\theta_2|\theta_1)=\int\limits^1_0\theta_2dF(\theta_2|\theta_1)=1-\int\limits^1_0F(\theta_2|\theta_1)$, integrating by parts. I know $F$ is continuous. But after this I'm confused if I can conclude $F(\theta_2|\theta_1)$ is continuous is $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following joint density of two random variables $X$ and $Y$:
$$
f(x,y)=\cases{1, & $0\le x\le 1,0\le y<1/2$, \\ 2(1-x), & $0\le x\le 1,1/2\le y\le 1$, \\ 0, & otherwise.}
$$
In this case
$$
\mathsf{E}[X\mid Y=y]=\frac{1}{2}\times 1_{[0,1/2)}(y)+\frac{1}{3}1_{[1/2,1]}(y).
$$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much. Do you think if we assume the joint density $f$ is continuous the continuity of $E(X|Y)$ can be restored?

Comment: Write
$$
\mathsf{E}[X\mid Y=y]=\int x \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}\, dx,
$$
taking $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)=0$ when $f_Y(y)=0$. Now, if we can take limits inside the integral, $\mathsf{E}[X\mid Y=y]$ is continuous if $f(x,y)$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks so much!